# Why does the list result returned by my function look funny?

Tags: racket, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop, racket-student-languages, repl-printed-representation

```
(define (evenList xs)
    (cond
        ((null? xs) '())   
        ((eq? (cdr xs) '()) '()) 
        (else (cons (cadr xs) (evenList (cddr xs))))))
```

I'm using this code but it doesn't create the list the way I want it. `(evenList (list 1 2 3 4))` evaluates to `(cons 2 (cons 4 '()))` in the REPL, but I want it to be like `(list 2 4)`.

Comment: '_but it doesn't create the list the way I want_' is not very helpful. What's the current result? What's the expected/required result?

Comment: (evenList (list 1 2 3 4)) 
The answer to this function in the above codes (cons 2 (cons 4 '())) 
but I want it to be like this (list 2 4)

Comment: Thank you mate it solved my problem

Comment: @DarKing -- I edited your question to clarify the problem and make it easier to find for future visitors; I hope that this is ok. I also moved my earlier comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works and gives the correct output as far as I can tell. I'm guessing that you are using the Beginning Student Language. The list `(2 4)` is represented as`(cons 2 (cons 4 '()))` in the REPL when using the Beginning Student Language; this same list is represented as `(list 2 4)` in the REPL when using the Intermediate Student Language. In `#lang racket` you would see this represented as `'(2 4)` in the REPL. In all cases the underlying list data structure is the same; this is just a matter of the printed representation of the list.

Comment: we really should make some specific tag for this "print-formatting" thing in Racket. these questions keep comping up, and having the tag would help with finding similar questions.

Comment: @WillNess -- that is a good idea. I looked for a dupe before I answered, and couldn't find anything; a tag would be helpful. Since printed representations are so important in lisps in general, I might nominate [tag:printed-representation]. At a glance, I don't see anything like it available right now.

Comment: good idea, I think. sure will get picked up by other languages as well, with rich surface syntax for data, like e.g. (I hear;)) Clojure. you should just go ahead and add this tag here on this Q. if for some reason you're not allowed to, ping me and I'll do it, I did it before too (with e.g. [tag:map-function]). but since you've come up with it, you should have the honors of doing it yourself. :)

Comment: how about we rename it as "repl-printed-representation", to be more specific? I've found and tagged only few questions so far, it's not a bother to go over and retag them. another option is to always also tag them as "repl", but the 5 tags limit sometimes doesn't allow that. what do you think? "printed-representation" seems too broad, could also include serialization issues, or be mistaken as such and get removed. (!)

Comment: @WillNess -- I'm not necessarily opposed to that, but I don't think of printed representations as just for the REPL. Lisp readers read printed representations, and can read them from files for example. I'm not sure that there is a gain by being more specific, but the REPL is also probably where most issues would appear for askers. I don't feel too strongly either way....

Comment: Yeah, I was typing when you added that; it is a fair point. OK, agreed.

Comment: great. now let's see if we get scorned by the meta crowd. :) :)

Comment: fingers crossed ;)